# Query only one item in a nested mongoose object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I currently am trying to query an item inside of a mongoose object

```
module.exports.getAvatarsByLastMessages = function(messages, callback){
    const query = {lastMessage: {with: messages}}
    User.find(query, 'avatar username', callback);
  };
```

however it doesn't work because my lastMessage has multiple items in it, like so

```
{lastMessage: {with: 'foo', identifier:'bar', message:'lol'}}
```

How would I query what I want from just the "with:" object? My query has worked on other functions with only one item, and I got the same function to work by hardcoding in the identifier and message objects.

I'm not quite sure how to handle this and I wasn't even sure where to start googling or searching stack overflow for the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ["*Query on Embedded/Nested Documents*" documentation page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/) is what you are looking for here.

The behavior of current syntax of using a document in the query predicate is described in the first section [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#match-an-embedded-nested-document).  As you have observed, the semantics are not what you are looking for:

> Equality matches on the whole embedded document require an exact match of the specified `<value>` document, including the field order.

Rather, you are looking to use [dot notation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field), e.g.:

```
    const query = {'lastMessage.with': messages}}
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pjQplXdH3Mm).

Comment: It solved it. Thanks. I tried that syntax before but it didn't work because I wasn't putting lastMessage.with in quotes. I never would have thought about that.